# Powershell Interaction with Excel (Highlighting Cells)

Tags: performance, excel, csv, powershell

I'm using Powershell to compare two, large csv files and output the rows which don't match.  Once the two output files are made (one for the differences on each), I bring them up on Excel.  Now I want to highlight the mismatching fields for the output to be easily read by my customer.  Starting where I open the files in Excel, my current code is:

```
$excel= New-Object -ComObject "excel.application"
$excel.Visible=$true
$ocomp1=$excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aja3885.BUD\Desktop\agclink-data-mining\agclink-data-mining\test1.csv")
$ocomp2=$excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aja3885.BUD\Desktop\agclink-data-mining\agclink-data-mining\test2.csv")
$comp1=$ocomp1.worksheets.item(1)
$comp2=$ocomp2.worksheets.item(1)
$Row=$comp1.UsedRange.rows.count
$Column=$comp1.UsedRange.columns.count
$comp1.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()|out-null
$comp2.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()|out-null
$i=1
for($i=2; $i -le $row; $i++)
{if($comp1.cells.item($i,1).value2 -eq 'pntval'){if($comp1.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=1'){$comp1.cells.item($i,4).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp1.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=2'){$comp1.cells.item($i,6).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp1.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=3'){$comp1.cells.item($i,5).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp1.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=4'){$comp1.cells.item($i,7).interior.colorindex=3}}}

for($i=2; $i -le $row; $i++)
{if($comp2.cells.item($i,1).value2 -eq 'pntval'){if($comp2.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=1'){$comp2.cells.item($i,4).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp2.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=2'){$comp2.cells.item($i,6).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp2.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=3'){$comp2.cells.item($i,5).interior.colorindex=3} elseif($comp2.cells.item($i,8).value2 -eq 'VALUTYPE=4'){$comp2.cells.item($i,7).interior.colorindex=3}}}
```

This code works, but the part which highlights the fields (the for loops on bottom) is cripplingly slow.  How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't a direct way to speed up PowerShell interaction with Excel, I suspect most people having this problem will find this helpful.  I ended up writing a VBA macro ("Sides") that opens in a third workbook, along with the two of interest.  I then call it from Powershell.  All together, I came up with:

```
$excel= New-Object -ComObject "excel.application"
$excel.Visible=$true
$ocomp1=$excel.Workbooks.Open($WorkingDirectory+"Discrepancies1.csv")
$ocomp2=$excel.Workbooks.Open($WorkingDirectory+"Discrepancies2.csv")
$macro=$excel.Workbooks.open("\\dshfs03.dgoz.dccz.ccnz\psst\Aram\Highlighter.xlsm")
$excel.run("Sides")
```

This runs really smoothly and does exactly what I want.  Granted, you have to know a little VBA, but that wasn't a problem for me.